What are the advantages of using the vue-router's route.param.x in computed value
Vue-router docs are giving 2 specific patterns of usage:
const route = useRoute();

// Get the current value
const id = route.params.id;

// Watch for further value changes
watch(
  () => route.params.id,
  (newValue, oldValue) => {
    console.log(`The value changed from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);
});

However in numerous online examples, I see that often the route is used as a computed reactive property:
const id = computed(() => route.params.id);

I wonder what is the advantage of computed in this case?
Seems this is not going to catch value changes, and just overcomplicates getting the value. Or am I missing something?

A computed can be expressed with a watcher and reactive object, i.e. a ref. It's up to you to use one or another. "Seems this is not going to catch value changes" - where does this conclusion come from? The snippets you show are not equivalent. There's no real use for "id", and the only thing that is done is console.log(). Which you shouldn't do in a computed, it should contain no side effects.

It is going to catch value changes. In a nutshell computed is just a shortcut for this:
const id = ref(route.params.id)

watch(
  () => route.params.id,
  (newValue) => {
    id.value = newValue
  }
)


Thanks. I am new to Vue, so didn't know they are the same thing.
